# Binding to 3rd-party library in Monotouch - mapping uint8_t * and uint8_t **

Tags: c#, c, binding, xamarin.ios

I am attempting to bind to a 3rd-party barcode scanning library using monotouch - everything is working well so far except the following method, as defined in the library header file:

```
/**
 * Main scan function. Invokes all activated decoders by priority.
 * For successful scan, allocates pp_data buffer and pass it to user.
 * User should deallocate *pp_data pointer when no more needed.
 *
 * @param[in]   pp_image                Byte array representing grayscale value of image pixels.
 *                                      Array shold be stored in row after row fashion, starting with top row.
 * @param[in]   lenX                    X axis size (width) of image.
 * @param[in]   lenY                    Y axis size (length) of image.
 * @param[out]  pp_data                 On successful decode, library allocates new byte array where it stores decoded
 *                                      string result. Pointer to string is passed here. User application is responsible
 *                                      for deallocating this buffer after use.
 *
 * @retval      >0                      Result string length for successful decode
 * @retval      MWB_RT_BAD_PARAM        Null pointer or out of range parameters
 * @retval      MWB_RT_NOT_SUPPORTED    Unsupported decoder found in execution list - library error
 */
extern int MWB_scanGrayscaleImage(uint8_t *  pp_image,  int lenX,  int lenY, uint8_t **pp_data);
```

It has been a while since I have dealt directly with C data structures, and I am not clear on how to map `uint8_t * pp_image` and `uint8_t **pp_data`.

The first parameter deals with the grayscale image from the pixel buffer.  I am getting an image buffer from the `CMSampleBuffer`.  Is it expecting a luminance-converted byte array, the memory address of the byte array, or will passing in `pixelBuffer.GetBaseAddress(0)` as an `IntPtr` suffice?

The last parameter gets passed in a pointer that gets initialized as `unsigned char *pResult=NULL;` in the objective-C demo, then gets filled with data when a valid scan is found.  Again, I am not sure how to initialize and pass this in, as you can't pass in an uninitialized/null byte array in C#.

My binding library code is currently as follows (although I have also tried using `IntPtr`, passing by ref, and passing direct addresses in unsafe mode):

```
[DllImport ("__Internal")]
extern static int MWB_scanGrayscaleImage (byte[] pp_image, int lenX, int lenY, out byte[] pp_data);
public static int ScanGrayscaleImage (byte[] pp_image, int lenX, int lenY, out byte[] pp_data)
{
    int result = MWB_scanGrayscaleImage(pp_image, lenX, lenY, out pp_data);
    return result;
}
```

For everything I have tried so far, the result value that keeps getting returned in -1, which maps to "scan failed".  Any help figuring this out would would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest binding the uint8_t** as an IntPtr since the library will not be able to allocate a managed byte[]

Perhaps something like this:

```
[DllImport ("__Internal")]
extern static int MWB_scanGrayscaleImage (byte[] pp_image, int lenX, int lenY, out IntPtr pp_data);
public static int ScanGrayscaleImage (byte[] image, int lenX, int lenY, out byte[] data)
{
    IntPtr pp_data;

    int result = MWB_scanGrayscaleImage (image, lenX, lenY, out pp_data);
    if (result > 0) {
        data = new byte[result];
        Marshal.Copy (pp_data, data, 0, result);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal (pp_data); // I think this is what you want...
    } else {
        data = null;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter is the memory address of the byte array holding the luminance values, but passing the array as parameter should do that.

The last parameter must reference a (valid) memory location where a reference to the output string will be stored.

Have you tried something like the following?

```
[DllImport ("__Internal")]
extern static int MWB_scanGrayscaleImage (byte[] pp_image, int lenX, int lenY, out byte[] pp_data);
public static int ScanGrayscaleImage (byte[] pp_image, int lenX, int lenY, out byte[] pp_data)
{
    int result;

    fixed (byte** pp_data_ptr = &pp_data) {
        result = MWB_scanGrayscaleImage(pp_image, lenX, lenY, pp_data_ptr);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I feel like I'm in the ballpark at least, but I'm getting an error on this line:

`fixed (byte** pp_data_ptr = &pp_data) {`

_Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type 'byte[]'_